# how to get the input data dynamically in android dynamic key value pairs in JSON format

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

While entering values in a  registration form that dynamic values should be taken in JSON format and have sent those values to DB.

Can anyone help how to get the dynamic data values in JSON format in RegistrationForm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/43802778/4336740

Answer (score 0):

**Try this my friend get dynamic key and value**

```
try
{
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        String value = jsonObject.getString(key);
        Log.v("**********", "**********");
        Log.v("category key", key);
        Log.v("category value", value);

    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```